# What does additional 0 parameter in JS do?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Consider this code:

```
let reduced = inventors.reduce((a, b) => {      
      return (b.passed - b.year) + a;
}, 0);
```

I don't understand what this additional 0 means. At first, I thought it is similar to setting default values, like this:

```
let reduced = inventors.reduce((a = 0, b) => {      
      return (b.passed - b.year) + a;
});
```

But it didn't work. The difference is, with the first code array was reduced successfully. The seconds returned some strange concatenated string.

PS This is the array I'm reducing(getting the sum of the lifespans of all inventors in the list):

```
const inventors = [
      { first: 'Albert', last: 'Einstein', year: 1879, passed: 1955 },
      { first: 'Isaac', last: 'Newton', year: 1643, passed: 1727 },
      { first: 'Galileo', last: 'Galilei', year: 1564, passed: 1642 },
      { first: 'Marie', last: 'Curie', year: 1867, passed: 1934 },
      { first: 'Johannes', last: 'Kepler', year: 1571, passed: 1630 },
      { first: 'Nicolaus', last: 'Copernicus', year: 1473, passed: 1543 },
      { first: 'Max', last: 'Planck', year: 1858, passed: 1947 },
      { first: 'Katherine', last: 'Blodgett', year: 1898, passed: 1979 },
      { first: 'Ada', last: 'Lovelace', year: 1815, passed: 1852 },
      { first: 'Sarah E.', last: 'Goode', year: 1855, passed: 1905 },
      { first: 'Lise', last: 'Meitner', year: 1878, passed: 1968 },
      { first: 'Hanna', last: 'Hammarström', year: 1829, passed: 1909 }
    ];
```

So, could somebody please explain to me what this 0 does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr.reduce(callback[, initialValue])
```

This is considered as initial value

If you don't use first element of array is considered as initial value

[**Reduce -> Initial value parameter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Parameters)

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.reduce(callback[, initialValue])
```

**initialValue Optional**

Value to use as the first argument to the first call of the callback. If no initial value is supplied, the first element in the array will be used. Calling reduce() on an empty array without an initial value is an error.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score -1):

The 0 in this case represents what is called an **accumulator**.
you can google and find on MDN a detailed description.

Basically what reduce does is take a function as it's first argument and accumulator as second and it combines both values to produce a new value.

If you do not pass an accumulator, the first element inside the array is set to be the default one.

Comment: That's not me)0)